# change raw query into django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i want to use django models feature to excute this sql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ques_id), title FROM contest_assignment WHERE grp_id = 60 GROUP BY title;
```

i tried this but it did not give me proper result:

> from django.db.models import Count
>   assignment.objects.values_list('title').annotate(count=Count('ques')).values('title', 'count')

how can i use django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use both `.values()` and `.values_list()`. The `count` field is implicitly added to the set of fields that is returned.

Django supports a `COUNT(DISTINCT <field>)` query by using `.annotate(count=Count('<field>', distinct=True))`. That would leave you with the following query:

```
(assignment.objects.filter(grp_id=60).values('title')
           .annotate(count=Count('ques_id', distinct=True)))
```